# Purpose of fraudulent AWS SL/TLS certificate request for my domain

Tags: phishing, aws, social-engineering, fraud

I just received an email from AWS re `Certificate request for  [my personal domain]`.

This email asked me to approve this request with a link or forward to a AWS email for validation.

Needless to say this request for the cert did not originate for me or anyone acting on my behalf.

I am posting here as I have never encountered a situation like this, I dont have any vocabulary to put this kind of attack in context, it seems tangential to a social engineering in the sense I dont see how it could be used in a social engineering attack.
I am in the dark and at a loss for how to even google for information about the context for this kind of attack.

My specific question is

`what could the perpetrators of this attack achive if they were able to obtain an aws cert for my domain.`

Edit: This is not the PKI keys you use for ssh, rather this is a certificate you would use with an aws service like cloudfront

Answer (score 1):

One of the protections people have against someone spoofing their domain is the cert. If you have HSTS turned on your domain, your users will always expect to see a proper certificate when visiting your site -- more specifically the browser will always expect a certificate on the TLS connection. Hence unless an attacker can get access to a 'proper' cert, browsers will always complain about the site to your users, in some cases forcefully prevent them from accessing it.

Initially I wondered, even with a cert, an attacker wouldn't be able to spoof your site unless they had access to modify your DNS records. But then there are scenarios (e.g. in a closed network, a coffeeshop, etc) where an attacker could control the DNS lookups -- and the only missing piece they'd need is the certificate to properly spoof your site. It's a stretch but possible.

I guess in summary, we can imagine someone redirecting users to a spoof-ed version of your website, but they'll still need a proper certificate, which might be what they're looking for here.

That being said -- this is most probably just someone making a typo on a domain rather than a specific attack.

Comment: thanks for the info re HSTS, the header is not currently set, so that's an issue I can address as a direct result of your answer